# Flutter Plugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

when I run my program flutter on android studio, I get the following error,and  i have a white screen in my device.

```
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_share-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\example\fluttershare\FlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63581/tYPCfAyfdsI=/ws
Syncing files to device LG M250...
E/flutter (12903): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project? 
E/flutter (12903):     
E/flutter (12903): View the Android Installation documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android
E/flutter (12903): 
E/flutter (12903): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:9)
E/flutter (12903): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12903): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41:31)
E/flutter (12903): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12903): #2      main (package:medecins_oran/main.dart:12:3)
E/flutter (12903): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12903):
```

Comment: Like it says, Firebase has not been correctly initialised. Refer to the Firebase and flutterfire docs on how to do that.